# How do I deserialize a JSON document into a Dictionary<string, List<object>>

Tags: c#, json, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON document into a class with only using the `Json*` tags on my class.

How do I do that when my JSON document looks like this?

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "name" : "test",
   "dictionary": [
                    {
                       "obj" : "a",
                       "list" : [{ "Id" : "1"} , { "Id" : "2"}]
                    },
                    {
                       "obj" : "b",
                       "list" : [{ "Id" : "3"} , { "Id" : "4"}]
                    }
                 ]

}
```

My C# class looks like this:

```
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string TestId {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("dictionary")]
    public Dictionary(string, List<object>) dict {get;set;}
}
```

However, it fails to deserialize into the dictionary.  My code right now is leveraging a documentDb query like this:

```
var response = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Test>(collection.DocumentsLink, "SELECT * FROM root r");
```

Comment: That's not a JSON dictionary - it's an array of objects.

Comment: Paste your json to [http://json2csharp.com/](http://json2csharp.com/) and Ta Da....

Comment: To be fair, it does appear that the list of objects each has a key (under the property "obj") and a value, so there's probably a way to set up the serializer to recognize the pattern and put it into a dictionary the way he wants.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Agreed, but that would require some custom deserialization code.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, what would a Json Dictionary look like then?  What I'm trying to achieve is having a Key equal to what "obj" is right now, and then the value being a list of Id's.   I come primarily from the relational data world, and json is somewhat new to me.

Comment: @NateBarbettini: Indeed. And your solution is the simplest and probably the best one. I'm just saying that if you were stuck using a specific class structure for some reason, there are other options.

Comment: @mike: If you have control over your JSON structure, and can change it to fit the C# model you've created, a JSON Dictionary is just a JSON object that leverages the dynamic nature of JavaScript, so the keys are just the names of properties on the object and the values are the properties' values. `"dictionary": {"a": [{...}, {...}], "b": [{...}, {...}], ...}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create POCO classes for each of the nested objects in your JSON object graph.

Try deserializing with the following classes:

```
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string TestId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dictionary")]
    public List<TestInnerItem> dictionary { get; set; }
}

public class TestInnerItem
{
    public string Obj { get; set; }

    public List<TestInnerInnerItem> List { get; set; }
}

public class TestInnerInnerItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```